# Flink interval join does not output

Tags: apache-flink

We have a Flink job that does [intervalJoin](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html#interval-join) two streams, both streams consume events from Kafka. Here is the example code

```
val articleEventStream: DataStream[ArticleEvent] = env.addSource(articleEventSource)
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new ArticleEventAssigner) 
val feedbackEventStream: DataStream[FeedbackEvent] = env.addSource(feedbackEventSource)
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new FeedbackEventAssigner) 

articleEventStream
    .keyBy(article => article.id)
    .intervalJoin(feedbackEventStream.keyBy(feedback => feedback.article.id))
    .between(Time.seconds(-5), Time.seconds(10))
    .process(new ProcessJoinFunction[ArticleEvent, FeedbackEvent, String] {
        override def processElement(left: ArticleEvent, right: FeedbackEvent, ctx: ProcessJoinFunction[ArticleEvent, FeedbackEvent, String]#Context, out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
         out.collect(left.name + " got feedback: " + right.feedback); 
        }
      });
});

class ArticleEventAssigner extends AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[ArticleEvent] {
  val bound: Long = 5 * 1000

  override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: ArticleEvent, extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
    new Watermark(extractedTimestamp - bound)
  }

  override def extractTimestamp(element: ArticleEvent, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
    element.occurredAt
  }
}

class FeedbackEventAssigner extends AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[FeedbackEvent] {
  val bound: Long = 5 * 1000

  override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: FeedbackEvent, extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
    new Watermark(extractedTimestamp - bound)
  }

  override def extractTimestamp(element: FeedbackEvent, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
    element.occurredAt
  }
}
```

However, we do not see any joined output. We checked that each stream does continuously emit elements with timestamp and proper watermark. Does anyone have any hint what could be possible reasons?

Comment: Can You extend Your code example?  Are the timestamps properly assigned?

Comment: @DominikWosiński Thanks for the comment! I updated the example code.

Comment: Unless your timestamps are never out-of-order, this will generate watermarks that can go backwards, which is not allowed. I'm not sure if Flink protects itself against this, or not.

Comment: @DavidAnderson in such case Flink will simply ignore the Watermark that was lower than the one that has been emitted previously.

Comment: I wasn't sure that was true for punctuated watermarks, but you're right, I found the check for that in TimestampsAndPunctuatedWatermarksOperator. So this is not the problem.

Comment: Maybe show us all of the code? The problem does not appear to be in what we can see now.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments! I just noticed that I made a mistake and I posted the answer. Hopefully this post and comments could be still be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking different parts (timestamp/watermark, triggers), I just noticed that I made a mistake, i.e., the window size I used

`between(Time.seconds(-5), Time.seconds(10))`

is just too small, which could not find elements from both streams to join. This might sound obvious, but since I am new to Flink, I did not know where to check.
So, my lesson is that if the join does not output, it could be necessary to check the window size. 
And thanks all for the comments!